# Qt display transparent animated gif

Tags: c++, qt, animated-gif

I want to display an animated gif image in Qt.

By using QMovie and QLabel, it can display the gif in the screen. However, the gif has the ghosting effect: the previous frames didn't disappear, so they overlapped with the frames after them.

How can I display an animated transparent background gif without this problem in QT? Hope someone can help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is with your GIF animation and not Qt. In a GIF, the frames are either of the "replace" type or of the "combine" one. With the "combine" the new frame is added on top of the current view, so you see the previous image where it is transparent. And probably your GIF is made only of "combine" frames.

You should try to change your GIF animation. I don't know which tool you are using to create your GIF animations. The options are different in various tools. They are like: "replace", "stacked" and "do not dispose".